# how to select multiple value handlebar

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, hbs

[image]

I have a table like this.I want to fetch it inside the select tag but it's not working exactly what i am looking. I have register handlebar custom helper

```
  selectOption(status, options) {
    return options.fn(this).replace(new RegExp(`value=\"${status}\"`), '$&selected="selected"');
},
```

And inside the edit.hbs file

```
 <select name="getUser" multiple class="form-control selectpicker">
                    {{#selectOption message.user.id}}
                    {{#each user}}
                    <option value="{{this.id}}">{{this.fullName}}</option>
                    {{/each}}
                    {{/selectOption}}
                </select>
```

Problem is  it's selecting only one user not multiple user on the edit page. how to set multiple select ?

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding. It looks like `message.user.id` has a single user id value. So what user id values do you expect to be selected?

Comment: multiple user id @76484

Comment: If `message.user.id` is an array containing multiple user IDs, then I don't understand the regular expression in your `selectOption` helper. The regex clearly intends for the `status` parameter to be a single id value, but the helper is invoked with `message.user.id` as its `status` arg. If the value of `status` is an array, then I don't see how even one option is getting the `selected` attribute.

Comment: @76484  i have solve the issue myself. yes there was a problem with `message.user.id`

Comment: Then I would suggest you delete your question if you are not looking for further help.